# How to get equal spacing in ssh with javascript console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, terminal, console

I'm running javascript with node.js and looking at the console.logs through Putty.

How can I get the terminal in ssh to show me things with the tabs inline? I see two tab spaces but the string following is out of place depending on how long the first string is.

```
console.log('short'+'\t\t'+'valueA');
console.log('looooooong'+'\t\t'+valueH);
```

I might get something like this

```
short        valueA
looooooong        valueH
```

whereas for readability it would be much nicer to see

```
short        valueA
looooooong   valueH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a module to handle this scenario, called [tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tab). You could do:

```
var mod_tab = require('tab');

mod_tab.emitTable({
  'columns': [{
    'align': 'left',
    'width': 12
  }, {
    'align': 'right',
    'width': 10
  }],
  'omitHeader': true,
  'rows': [
    ['short', 'valueA'],
    ['looooooooong', 'valueH']
  ]
});
```

It has some interesting features, that you could check out by reading [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tab#output-overview).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using console.table.

For example:

```
var people = [
      {'FIRST NAME': 'John', 'LAST NAME': 'SMITH'},
      {'FIRST NAME': 'Jane', 'LAST NAME': 'Donate'},
      {'FIRST NAME': 'Emily', 'LAST NAME': 'Jones'}
]
console.table(people)
```

Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iIX5.png)

More information: [console.log documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Console/table)